# Bubble Sort is printing out in incorrect order?

Tags: arrays, sorting

So my BubbleSort is printing the elements of my array not in the correct order. In this case it prints out:
4
5
1
3.

I thought I wrote the program correctly but 
 I have absolutely no idea what to do about this and all advice is appreciated, thank you!

```
  public class BubbleSort {



    public void Print(){

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        int[] BubbleSort = {1, 5, 4, 3};    
            int lengthOfArray = BubbleSort.length;

            for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfArray; i++){
                for (int n = 1; n < lengthOfArray - i; n++){
                    if (BubbleSort[n - 1] > BubbleSort[n]){
                         Swap(i, n , BubbleSort);
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int i=0;i < lengthOfArray ;i++){
                System.out.println( BubbleSort[i]); 
                }
    }



     private static void Swap(int index1, int index2, int[] array) {       
         int temp;
         temp = array[index1];
         array[index1] = array[index2];
         array[index2] = temp;
     }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [tour] to familiarize yourself with the very basics. "I have absolutely no idea" – does that also go for the programming language you are using here? I suppose adding the proper tag for it may attract the eyes of the proper experts in it.

Answer (score 0):

In a bubble sort, you look at each element in the sequence, and then swap any element after the one looked at if it is less. In you're code, you don't stay on the element you want to compare:

```
if (BubbleSort[n - 1] > BubbleSort[n])
```

You need to stay on the element you are looking at:

```
if (BubbleSort[i] > BubbleSort[n])
```

Then, in the inner loop, you start at the element after the one you are comparing, and continue until the end of the sequence:

```
for (int n = i + 1; n < lengthOfArray; n++)
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm looks fine *except* for your `Swap()` method.  Change it to this and all should be good:

```
private static void Swap(int index, int[] array) {
    int temp = array[index - 1];
    array[index - 1] = array[index];
    array[index] = temp;
 }
```

Use the method like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfArray; i++) {
    for (int n = 1; n < lengthOfArray - i; n++) {
        if (BubbleSort[n - 1] > BubbleSort[n]) {
            Swap(n, BubbleSort);
        }
    }
}
```